# Does an updated 'vimtutor' exist?

Tags: vim, open-source, project, interactive

vim comes with a nice built-in interactive tutorial. You can access this tutorial by just running:

```
 $ vimtutor
```

It is very easy to use because it creates working cases for basic commands.  Is there a more advanced tutorial?  Has any one thought to build one to help uses take their VIM skills to the next level?  Most tutorial and cheat-sheet sites out there for vim only show commands but not necessarily specific uses and examples.

Is there an advanced tutorial out there?
Is this the type of project that could be an open source document that everyone can add examples to? Like a Vim Interactive Wiki or similar to the RegEx sites that have the built in regex testers.

Comment: I don't want to get rep off somebody else's answer, but the first answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim taught me a lot about advanced vim usage.

Comment: Voting for closing this because if you're asking for vim tutorials in general, that means you haven't invested any effort in searching either on this site or google. And I don't close questions often.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim Tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573/vim-tutorials)

Comment: @indigas this question is for interactive tutorial

Answer (score 8):

It's not exactly a tutorial, but I've been impressed with @nelstrom's growing collection of screencasts at vimcasts.org:

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/archive

Each short video covers a single topic (or a small set of closely-related topics), and the ones I've watched have been informative and enjoyable. The author says that "the aim is to provide something in each episode that you can take away and use," and I'd say he's succeeding.

Answer (score 8):

Try the interactive vim tutorial online here: http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in a game for Vim, there's [Vim-Adventures](http://vim-adventures.com/). As of April 22, 2013, it has 12 levels and covers a wide berth of topics. If you like it, you can buy it. There is also [VimGolf](http://www.vimgolf.com/) for sharpening very specific golfing skills. It's not useful on average, but take a look at some of the impressive entries.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who prefer books I think **Practical Vim: Edit Text at the Speed of Thought** by **Drew Neil** does the perfect job as a continuation for `vimtutor`

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a more modern and interactive system for tutorials inside vim, [vim-tutor-mode](https://github.com/fmoralesc/vim-tutor-mode). The goal is to provide an updated tutorial for newcomers, and a way for third party developers to create tutorials for plugins. It currently has an updated version of vimtutor, and some more things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the various stuff in `:help`? `:help` to get a general table of contents, `:help usr_toc` to access the table of contents of the User Manual -- chapters 20 through 32 of the user manual are on advanced editing topics, as is everything under the "Advanced Editing" heading in the main TOC. Chapters 40-44 of the manual discuss programming vim.

Comment: The help files and all advanced resources are extremely helpful but they lack specific examples for each feature.  Nor interactive exercises.