# Is there a continuation to vimtutor, something in the same style?

Tags: vim

I've run through the vimtutor and I'm curious if there is a follow-up in the same style. Any good continuation in the same style? Not necessarily official.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official continuation.  The best way to continue learning vim is to use vim.  You might be interested in the answers to a previous question [Does an updated 'vimtutor' exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567883/does-an-updated-vimtutor-exist)