# How does one align code (braces, parens etc) in vi?

Tags: format, vi, alignment

How do you prettify / align / format code in vi? What is the command?

I have pasted in a hunk of code and I need to have it all formatted/aligned... obviously I am a vi neophyte.

x

Answer (score 48):

These commands in my answer work in vim.  Most people who think they're using vi are using vim.  To find out if your 'vi' is really 'vim', open vi and type `:version` -- if it's vim, it will say so.  Otherwise you might just see a version number without the name of the program.  Also, when you open vim for the first time you will usually see a splash screen of some sort that says "VIM - VI iMproved"...

**Automatic Indentation**

To turn auto-indentation on, make sure vim knows the file type you're editing (it usually automatically detects this from the file name extension, but might not figure it out with some file types).   You can tell it the filetype using the menus for syntax highlighting.  Then, do this:

```
:filetype indent on
```

You can disable auto-indentation with

```
:filetype indent off
```

**Automatically adjusting/correcting indentation**

In general, **=**{motion} will align code to an indentation level.

- **`==`** align the current line
- **`=i{`** align the inner block
- **`=%`** align to the matching parenthesis/bracket under the cursor
- **`=14j`** or **`14==`** align the next 14 lines
- **`=G`** align to the end of the file
- **`vG=`** same thing, align to the end of the
  file (but using visual mode)
- **`vjjj=`** align four lines (using visual mode)

**Manual indentation**

If vim is not guessing the indentation level correctly, there are two ways to change it:

- If you are in normal mode (where everything is a command), do **`<<`** to shift a line left, or **`>>`** to shift it right by one tab.  You can do this with several lines by using the same movement commands I showed above (eg, **`>i{`** indents the current inner code block).
- If you are in insert mode, you can indent the line further (without moving the cursor) by doing a **Ctrl-T**, or un-indent one tab with **Ctrl-D**

**Aligning equals signs, etc**

If you want to align equals signs in a list of declarations, you should consider using this vim script: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294

**Adjusting indentation/tab sizes**

If you want vim to use spaces instead of tabs when it indents, run this command (or consider adding it to your vimrc file)

```
 :set expandtab
```

To set how many spaces equal a tab, I usually do this:

```
 :set expandtab softtabstop=3 tabstop=3 shiftwidth=3
```

- tabstop - how many columns a tab counts for (affects display of existing tab characters)
- shiftwidth - controls reindentation size with << and >>, among other commands.
- softtabstop - how much space to insert when you press the tab key
- expandtab - expand tab keys to spaces

But if you have to work with different amounts of tabs a lot, you could also use this function and keybinding:

```
function! Ktabs(tabsize)
    execute "set softtabstop=" . a:tabsize . " tabstop=" . a:tabsize . " expandtab shiftwidth=" . a:tabsize
    "set softtabstop=a:tabsize tabstop=a:tabsize expandtab shiftwidth=a:tabsize
endfunction
noremap <leader><Tab> :call Ktabs(3)<Left>
```

If you are editing a file with a mix of tabs and spaces, you may want to use this command after setting tab size:

```
:retab
```

Comment: Also, if you wish to change the default indent levels you can :set shiftwidth=n and :set tabstop=n  where n is the desired level of spaces.

Comment: @SplittingField, good point.  I tend to :set expandtab so that spaces are inserted instead of literal tabs, but if you do this then you may also need :set softtabstop=n

Answer (score 5):

`={motion}`

`:h =`

P.S. You shouldn't use vi if vim is available.

Comment: I will read the basics ... but could you explain this command?

x

Comment: `{motion}` is a command that moves the cursor such as `w` or `4j`. `=` command is applied to the range covered by `{motion}`.

Answer (score 4):

If manually adjusting indents I will open a visual block with `V` on the first or last line I want to re-indent, move to the brace containing the block, goto the other brace with `%` then shift the line with `>` or `<`

If indents are off by a lot I will shift everything all the way left with `<` and repeat it with `.` and then re-indent everything.

Another solution is to use the unix `fmt` command as described in [Your problem with Vim is that you don't grok vi.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118), `{!}fmt`

Comment: Note that visual mode isn't available in vi.