# How can I delete multiple lines in vi?

Tags: vi

I have tried to follow the following:

[How to delete selected text in VI editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114936/how-to-delete-selected-text-in-vi-editor)

but

```
5dd
```

gives

> E492: Not an editor command: 5dd

I then tried:

```
5d
```

Which only deletes a single line.  How can I delete multiple lines?

Comment: As far as I recall, 5dd should be valid syntax and should delete 5 lines starting with the one the cursor is on.  Any chance CAPS LOCK is on and you use a keyboard layout that causes the numeric keys to shift when it is?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Sounds like you're entering the commands in command mode (aka. "Ex mode"). In that context `:5d` would remove line number 5, nothing else. For `5dd` to work as intended -- that is, remove five consequent lines starting at the cursor -- enter it in normal mode and don't prefix the commands with `:`.

Answer (score 196):

I find this easier

1. Go VISUAL mode <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
2. Select lines
3. <kbd>d</kbd> to delete

https://superuser.com/questions/170795/how-can-i-select-and-delete-lines-of-text-in-vi

Answer (score 160):

You can delete multiple(range) lines if you know the line numbers:

```
:[start_line_no],[end_line_no]d
```

**Note:** d stands for delete

where,
 start_line_no is the beginning line no you want to delete and
 end_line_no is the ending line no you want to delete.
 The lines between the start and end, including start and end will be deleted.

Eg:

```
:45,101d
```

The lines between 45 and 101 including 45 and 101 will be deleted.

Comment: You can use `$` to denote the last line in the file too. So `:45,$d` would delete every line from 45 until the end.

Comment: You can even use Patterns like `/<\/div>/`

Comment: If you want to start the range from the lne you are currently on you can do `:.,[end_line_no]d`

Answer (score 20):

Commands listed for use in normal mode (prefix with <kbd>:</kbd> for command mode).

Tested in Vim.

By line amount:

- *num*<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> - will delete *num* lines DOWN starting count from current cursor position (e.g. <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> will delete current line and 4 lines under it => **deletes current line and (*num-1*) lines under it**)
- *num*<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> - will delete *num* lines UP from current line and current line itself (e.g. <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> will delete current line and 3 lines above it => **deletes current line and *num* lines above it**)

By line numbers:

- <kbd>d</kbd>*num*<kbd>G</kbd> - will delete lines **from current line (inclusive) UP to line number *num* (inclusive)** (e.g. if cursor is currently on line 5 <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will delete lines 2-5 inclusive)
- <kbd>d</kbd>*num*<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> - will delete lines **from current line (inclusive) DOWN to the line number *num* (inclusive)** (e.g. if cursor is currently on line 2 <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> will delete lines 2-6 inclusive)
- (**command mode only**) <kbd>:</kbd>*num1*<kbd>,</kbd>*num2*<kbd>d</kbd> - will delete lines **line number *num1* (inclusive) DOWN to the line number *num2* (inclusive)**. Note: if *num1* is greater than *num2* — vim will react with `Backwards range given, OK to swap (y/n)?`

Comment: This helped me because I didn't realize num 'd' 'd' was trying to delete below cursor. I had my cursor at bottom of the file trying to delete the lines above my cursor! thanks for the help!

Comment: Deleting by linenumber: ':<start>,$d'  will delete until the end of the file.

Answer (score 12):

If you prefer a non-visual mode method and acknowledge the line numbers, I would like to suggest you an another straightforward way.

Example

> I want to delete text from line 45 to line 101.

My method suggests you to type a below command in command-mode:

```
45Gd101G
```

It reads:

> Go to line 45 (`45G`) then delete text (`d`) from the current line to
>   the line 101 (`101G`).

Note that on `vim` you might use `gg` in stead of `G`.

Compare to the @Bonnie Varghese's answer which is:

```
:45,101d[enter]
```

The command above from his answer requires 9 times typing including <kbd>enter</kbd>, where my answer require 8 - 10 times typing. Thus, a speed of my method is comparable.

Personally, I myself prefer `45Gd101G` over `:45,101d` because I like to stick to the syntax of the vi's command, in this case is:

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| syntax  | <motion> | <operator><motion> |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| command |   45G    |        d101G       |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 9):

d5d "cuts" five lines

I usually just throw the number in the middle like:

d7l = delete 7 letters

Answer (score 7):

Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to make sure your are not in an edit mode.
Place the cursor on the first line to be deleted.
Enter `:5dd`.
The current line, and the next four lines should be deleted.

Alternately, if you have line numbering turned on...

Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to make sure your are not in an edit mode.
Enter `:#,#d` where '#' stands for the beginning and ending line numbers to be deleted.

Comment: I do not think that it works with colon at the beginning.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Those are valid vi commands. The colon causes vi to move the cursor to the bottom of the screen and accept a line editor command.

Answer (score 6):

1. <kbd>Esc</kbd> *to exit insert mode*
2. <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> *go to line 1 (replace '1' with the line you are interested in)*
3. <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> *delete 5 lines (from the current line)*

*Type* **`:set number`** *(for numbered lines).*

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete a range AFTER a specific line trigger you can use something like this

```
:g/^TMPDIR/ :.,+11d
```

That deletes 11 lines (inclusive) after every encounter of `^TMPDIR`.

Answer (score 0):

it is dxd, not ddx

if you want to delete 5 lines, cursor to the beginning of the first line to delete and d5d

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the lines use - ESC gg dG
To delete few lines lets say 5 then use ESC 5dd