# Delete the current line and the preceeding n-1 lines

Tags: vim

`5dd` will delete the current line and the following four lines. How do we delete the current line and the preceding four lines?

Edit: my best attempt is `d4k` which may well be the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete multiple lines in vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912868/how-can-i-delete-multiple-lines-in-vi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I am aware `d4k` is the best answer.

If you wanted you could also do it with a backwards range in the ex mode using `:-4,.d` which can be simplified to `:-4,d`.  These commands should all have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete by line amount the best answer would be `d4k` or `4dk` as already mentioned by you and `B. Ackerman`

`d4k` / `4dk` will delete 4 lines up from current line and current line itself

If you want to delete by line numbers you have the following options:

`dnumG` / `numdG` - will delete lines from current line (inclusive) up to given line number (inclusive)

Or in command mode:
`:num1,num2d` - will delete from line number `num1` (inclusive) DOWN to the line number `num2` (inclusive). vim will react with `Backwards range given, OK to swap (y/n)?` if `num1` is bigger than `num2`