# How set that vim number style

Tags: vim

I want to set vim with that. but I can't find the way.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vim line numbers - how to have them on by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274146/vim-line-numbers-how-to-have-them-on-by-default)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following

```
:set nu
:set rnu
```

For more information use `:help`

```
:h number
:h relativenumber
```

Comment: thanks.I find that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151491/relative-number-in-vim