# error in .vimrc file

Tags: vim

```
e
n  " Automatically detect file types.
set nocompatible  " We don't want vi compatibility.

" Add recently accessed projects menu (project plugin)
set viminfo^=!

" Minibuffer Explorer Settings
let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavVim = 1
let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavArrows = 1
let g:miniBufExplMapCTabSwitchBufs = 1
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1

" alt+n or alt+p to navigate between entries in QuickFix
map <silent> <m-p> :cp <cr>
map <silent> <m-n> :cn <cr>

" Change which file opens after executing :Rails command
let g:rails_default_file='config/database.yml'

syntax enable
```

and here's the error I got:

```
Espresso:ruby PowerBook$ vim .vimrc
".vimrc" [New File]
Error detected while processing /Users/PowerBook/.vimrc:
line    2:
E163: There is only one file to edit
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I'm new to vi.Could anyone give me a reference of all this syntaxes mean? It's so overwhelming for me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the problem is in the 1st and 2nd line.

```
e
n  " Automatically detect file types.
```

These `e` and `n` are Vi(m) (ex) commands on the start of the lines (but in `.vimrc` they don't need the `:` prefix.

See their documentation at http://www.polarhome.com/vim/manual/v72/editing.html#:edit_f and http://www.polarhome.com/vim/manual/v72/editing.html#:next .

So they mean `e` edit file but there is no argument, so it's probably an error (usually most of the people doesn't specify `e` command(s) in their `.vimrc`

`n` means next (buffer), but as far as You does not specify more files on the commandline to start `vim`, it can't work, as there are no more buffers.

IMHO you should delete those commands from your `.vimrc`.

HTH

Comment: as a newbie to vi,It's very helpful information, Thanks Zsoft

Answer (score 0):

it's the `n` character, which is a command to go to next file. Also `e` does not make much sense in `.vimrc` as it just reloads the file you just loaded...

The syntax of the `.vimrc` is just normal vim commands - you can think of it as you'd enter the file by hand, adding `:` to the beginning of every line.

You probably want your config file to look like:

```
" Automatically detect file types.
set nocompatible  " We don't want vi compatibility.

" Add recently accessed projects menu (project plugin)
set viminfo^=!

" Minibuffer Explorer Settings
let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavVim = 1
let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavArrows = 1
let g:miniBufExplMapCTabSwitchBufs = 1
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1

" alt+n or alt+p to navigate between entries in QuickFix
map <silent> <m-p> :cp <cr>
map <silent> <m-n> :cn <cr>

" Change which file opens after executing :Rails command
let g:rails_default_file='config/database.yml'

syntax enable
```

This old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/) and it's top rated answers are probably the most mindblowing reference to vim. I suggest also reading some [vim tutorials](http://www.google.fi/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vim+tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the resources,I pretty enjoy reading them,