# Is there any shortcut to move cursor to previous/next blank line in xCode like vim?

Tags: xcode, vim, shortcut, text-cursor

In **Vim**, we can move cursor to previous/next blank line with a shortcut **{** or **}**.
How about **xCode**?

Reference: [What are the most-used vim commands/keypresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400806/what-are-the-most-used-vim-commands-keypresses)

Comment: No, the Vim commands are `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but there's a nice Vim keybinding plugin for Xcode which **does** have this shortcut.

It was renamed from XVim to XVim2 and can now be found [here](https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim2).

Comment: I didn't know such a plugin existed. That'd be a workaround.