# Open last opened files and tabs in gVim

Tags: vim

So I'm using the `gVim` editor to code in c++, and I would like that everytime I re-open gVim the previous tabs+files get restored. I tried adding that to my `_vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimLeave * nested let buffernr = bufnr("$") |
\ let buflist = [] |
\ while buffernr > 0 |
\   if buflisted(buffernr) |
\       let buflist += [ bufname(buffernr) ] |
\   endif |
\   let buffernr -= 1 |
\ endwhile |
\ if (!isdirectory($HOME . "/.vim")) |
\   call mkdir($HOME . "/.vim") |
\ endif |
\ call writefile(reverse(buflist), $HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt")

autocmd VimEnter * nested if argc() == 0 && filereadable($HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt") |
\   for line in readfile($HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt") |
\       if filereadable(line) |
\       execute "tabedit " . line |
\       set bufhidden=delete |
\       endif |
\   endfor |
\   tabclose 1 |
\ endif
```

However this does not work, I took it from [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Open_the_last_edited_file)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `vim  "+'0"` works from the command line. Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397895/7976758, found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+last+edited+file

Comment: Also think about [sessions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#views-sessions); https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+sessions

Comment: Thank you @phd however I need to put that inside my vimrc for my vim editor interface gVim.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Save session in `VimLeavePre` with `mksession!` and restore it with `gvim -S`.

Comment: I have an alias to open the last edited file: `lvim='vim -c "normal '\''0"'`

Comment: @Matt Thank you for your response, could you provide an answer, I can't quite see how I could do that... Thanks.

Comment: Have you read `:h Session`?

Comment: @Matt No I haven't let me do that now

Comment: @Matt Oh actually that's a really good idea! Let me try to do that. I'll post an answer if i managed to get it working...

Comment: @Alex you might be interested in tpope’s obsession plugin and the command flag vim -S