# Where is the grammar for all of the VIM commands?

Tags: vim

I have read several questions here regarding clever and seldomly used commands for VIM.  However, I haven't seen the grammar for VIM.  Does anyone know where I can find it?

References:

[What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95072/what-are-your-favorite-vim-tricks

Comment: What do you mean by "the grammar for VIM"?

Comment: If you want something like [count]command[motion|text-object] I think it's fairly consistent and easy to get from Vim's own documentation and, once you know a few commands, easy to apply to new situations. See `:help join` for example: `:[range]j[oin][!] [flags]`. That's what I understand by "grammar for VIM", is that what you mean?.

Comment: @romainl - I was hoping for a definitive BNF type grammar.  Does this exist?

Comment: It's funny to reply to no one in particular. Anyway I'm out of my league here (I had to google around to see what BNF stands for). Most of the Vim users here are just that, users. Maybe you'd have more luck on the dev mailing list : http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question to sharpen your googling teeth on.  Here's what I found:

http://www.vim.org/docs.php

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late to the game, but I found some very good answers in the following articles:

[The Grammar of Vim](http://rc3.org/2012/05/12/the-grammar-of-vim/)

[Learn to speak vim – verbs, nouns, and modifiers!](http://yanpritzker.com/2011/12/16/learn-to-speak-vim-verbs-nouns-and-modifiers/)

These have greatly increased my understanding of Vim.