# Delete lines backwards

Tags: vim, vi

Is there a shortcut for `10k10dd`? I want to delete the 10 lines prior to the cursor, without having to move the cursor backwards first.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you try something like `d10k` ?

Comment: This is the vim way. With the relativenumber feature this is very easy too ;)

Comment: In my vim both of these delete the line that I am on, not what the questioner asked for.

Comment: @ACRL:  `d9k` delete exactly the same lines as `10k10dd` does.  Just use `kd9k` to keep the current line.

Comment: @ib, your comment should really be an answer

Answer (score 2):

In certain circumstances, those 10 lines are the beginning of a paragraph than you can delete with:

- `d{`

or the beginning of a ( C-like) function

- `d[[`

See `:help object-motions` for more details and ideas.

It is usually easier to use text objects than to count lines. ( Well on Vim latest versions, you can use `set rnu` to avoid manually counting backward or forward lines.)

Answer (score 1):

You could select the lines that you want to delete in `visual` mode and then `d`elete those.

Comment: That sounds worse than `10k10dd` to me.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But in visual mode I do not have to count the number of lines upto where to delete. That method is prone to errors.

Comment: Did not think about that, because I only thought about the situation where you know the amount of lines to delete.

Comment: Not a problem :). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118 also.

Comment: Counting lines is easy if you have line numbers turned on and relative line numbers enabled.

Comment: Visual mode still works with known line counts: `V9kd` and you can adjust up and down before hitting `d`.