# Exclude string from regular expression

Tags: regex

Is there a way to select only those lines from a text file which exclude a substring?For example, I have the file:

```
I have a /apple
I have a peach
I have a cucumber/strawberry
ABCDE
I have a apple/grape
XYZEF
POLSD
```

and i want to select the lines that start with 'I have a' but don't include the string 'apple'.So basically I want to select only:

```
I have a peach
I have a cucumber/strawberry
```

Comment: What application or programming language? If you're using `grep`, it has a `-v` option that prints the lines that don't match.

Comment: More generally, you can use negative lookahead.

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative lookahead.

```
^I have a (?!.*\bapple\b).+
```

will match all "I have a" strings except ones that contain the entire word "apple". This will still match the phrase

```
I have a pineapple
```

because of the word boundaries around "apple".

Answer (score 1):

Use a pipe:

```
grep '^I have a' file.txt | grep -v apple
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the regular expression "starts with" with a multiline flag like this:
"**^I have a.***" /**gm**.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question, as this doesn’t really help OP.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure regex solution, you can use something like:

`^I have a (?!.*apple)` - Note: You can also add `\b` word boundaries around the "apple", like Jongware suggested, if you don't want to match things like "pineapple".

However, a much easier way to do this (especially if the problem was a bit more complicated!) would be to combine a search for the first pattern, with a search excluding the second pattern.

With `grep`, as suggested by Danny Daglas, you can do `grep '^I have a' file.txt | grep -v apple` (where `grep -v` is an "inverse grep").

However, you wanted to do this inside a text editor, which is fair enough. The exact method obviously varies between text editors, but for example for Vim check out [this excellent stackoverflow answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11854730/1954610)r.