# remap or ignore spacebar in vi

Tags: vim, keyboard

Vim/vi shortcuts are awesome, but there is one behavior that I would be very happy if it could be configured. My machine uses Brazilian Portuguese(abnt2) keyboard map,and some accents(like caret) needs an extra spacebar to be print, obviously because they wait/expect another character, mostly vowels. Example of the "cut until you find an empty line":

```
  d/^$
```

Keystrokes actually needed on br-abnt2:

```
  d / <shift + ~ , spacebar>(to result ^) $ <enter>
```

I could use `{ d }` as it is explained on [this awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim) thread, but i would benefit much more on other accents(backslash) where the extra backspace trick is needed, and most important, without change my keyboard mapping to "US" for example.

**Edit:** I also know that this is a keymap limitation, since our language expect something after the accent, and this is why i'm asking if there is a way to circunvent this limitation inside vim.

Any ideas?

Comment: The space bar is not the problem, here: it's the thing that allows you to insert what is essentially a "non-character". Usually, hitting two times on `^` is enough.

Comment: Try prefixing with <Ctrl>v to escape the next character.

Comment: Yeah. I know that this is a keymap limitation, and the space is just the thing I USE to insert the caret without a vowel. And that is why i was poking arround, to see if there is a way to circunvent the keymaping limitations inside vim ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not come from the editor, but your keymap. In fact, the `caret` is set to be a "dead key". Meaning that it should wait for other input before being printed.

What you probably need is a new keymap that has the `caret` as a non dead-key. As for example, uk-gb map has `caret` on the  key as well as another dead-key ( if I remember correctly).

If you don't want/can't remap your keyboard, you can use vim mapping function do act so.
Just choose an unused key and map it like this:

```
imap g ^
```

This will insert `^` while typing `g` on insert mode (other mapping for other- mode exists, nmap, ...).
For example, to use the vim mapping in the vim command-line, you shall use :

```
cmap g ^
```

Then your example will be working.

Comment: Yeah. I know that the problem is with my keyboard layout, the same way i would be happy to find a solution that could change the "dead key behavior" of caret, the same way i don't need to change my keymap.

Your answer is pretty usefull on insert mode, but will not work under "movements" like explained above :( - Thanks for your tip :)

Comment: Actually `nmap ' ^` does work on movements. It may be somehow unresponsible on the different other keys depending on the existing other shortcut beginning with this key (example g). Check them out with `:map <key>`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, it does not work with your example. I'll check if other mappings work.

Comment: Wow. That worker like a charm, Kudos for you. Now i will map any key that is "unused" to ^  -  d/g$  :)