# Delete a block of text in Vim

Tags: vim

So I can delete a text+line using <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (normal mode) and all the below text moves up a line.

I can go into visual mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

If I then say do `0` > `C+v` > `jjj` > `$` > `d` the text of 4 rows is deleted but the lines are not deleted.

How do I delete a block of text and delete the lines at the same time so any preceding lines of text move up to the cursor?

Comment: @hammar - how do I turn my `C+v` in OP into pictures of little buttons - I see it on some posts?

Comment: Use `<kbd>...</kbd>` tags, e.g. `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>`. Don't overdo it, though. Long Vim commands are often easier to read with the normal code markup.

Comment: @hammar - ok - I do have a tendency to overdo new tricks (check timss answer out ...is that ok or overdoing it?)

Comment: I'd say that's pushing it a little. But that's subjective, of course. Anyway, we're getting off topic here. Ask on [meta] if you want some more opinions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For something like this I usually use <kbd>shift+v</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>...<kbd>d</kbd>, but you could delete using text objects as well.
See `:h text-object`. A few examples:

`di"` - delete inside `"`
`dap` - delete around paragraph

And you could of course use other commands than `d`, such as `c` or `v`.
Something I use all the time is `ci(` and `ci"` for editing content inside `()` and `""`.

More cool examples using text-objects and visual mode can be found here:
[What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim)

---

You could use  as well, i.e. `4dd` as mentioned by FDinoff, or a range, mentioned by Jens. However in most scenarios I personally believe using visual line (<kbd>shift+v</kbd>) is more flexible, and you don't have to count lines or anything. It's easy to remember, you see the result instantly, you won't miss counting lines and it'll work even if you're at the top/bottom on the screen.

Comment: +1 thanks for that reference - stared and saved to read later

Comment: Props for the formatting, though I think it's often better to use the normal notation for Vim commands instead of `<kbd>` markup. There is no unshifted `"` key or `(` key so it doesn't really make sense to use `<kbd>` for them.

Comment: @timss - some <kbd> markup would have been nice - think you might have over-reacted!

Comment: @whytheq I can't really tell what's best since `d` etc. is both a command but also a mapping. Anyway, I think it's all right now.

Comment: @timss - for all the markup madness I'd better mark this as the answer

Comment: @whytheq Thanks, I appriciate it.

Comment: @timss If there exist another `{ }` block inside outer `{ }` block then `di{` doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

Use either `4dd` to delete 4 lines of text.

Or

Use linewise visual block. `<S-v>` then move to the last line you want to delete then press `d`

Comment: 4dd is the obvious simple answer - thanks! seems like just `v` followed by selecting the lines and pressing `d` is ok aswell - my mistake was using `C+v`

Answer (score 7):

If the block is really large, and you can't be bothered to count the number of lines to delete, but you know the first and last line numbers (`:set number` helps), you can always go to ex mode and

```
 :3,1415d
```

to delete from line 3 through line 1415.

Answer (score 7):

`<C-v>` puts you in "visual block mode". In that mode, you act on a rectangle (the "block" in "visual block mode") that may or may not cover the lines you want to delete. `d` only acts on the characters contained in that block, leaving the lines as is.

What you want is "visual line mode" where you specifically act on lines. From normal mode or from any other visual mode, hit `V` (Shift + v), move your cursor to define your selection then hit `d`.

Comment: +1 nice summary - that was my mistake and that is my solution (4dd in normal mode is probably the simplest solution though ...although good for me to practice visual line mode)

Answer (score 3):

delete 4 lines of text, starting at the line the cursor is on:

```
4dd
```

or use the ex command d with line addressing, for example:

```
:3,24d
```

would delete lines 3-24.

.

.

.

Here's some useful special characters when using line addressing with ex:

```
 .       : current line
 $       : last line
 /text/  : next occurrence of text
 ?text?  : previous occurrence of text
 *       : all text currently on screen
 %       : entire file
 +n      : next n lines
 -n      : previous n lines
```

Answer (score 1):

or `d with motion` e.g.

```
d3j
```

also the `:d` command is flexible too. check the help for detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use the book marks. Mark the first line with book mark, say, 'e'
In command mode (press ESC if in INSERT mode) press

```
m e
```

that marks the first line with bookmark 'e'.

Then go to the last line you want to remove 
and bookmark that, with say 'f'

```
m f
```

You can then goto ex mode (using colon) and delete the lines

```
:'e,'f d
```