# setup a cron job at One(Single ) time?

Tags: php, linux, cron

How to execute cron job in single time ? 
example : I need to execute cron job after 5 minutes later when I setup(but no need to call each and every 5 minutes after, I  need only once  execution of cron ).

Comment: for 5 minutes i would use sleep() and call a cli

Comment: just set the entry for the single time and date that is 5 minutes later, i.e. `08 23 05 04 * cmd ...` (given that now is 23:03 ). Good luck.

Comment: try 'at' commnd - http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm 
and how run
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945669/linux-how-to-run-script-at-certain-time