# Run jobs at a specific time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have certain jobs to be run in a specific time .

for example :

`at 00:20:00 ls`

`at 04:20:00 ls -l`

`at 08:20:00 ls -ltr`

`at 12:20:00 ls -ltrh`

How can run this at these specific time based on some conditions . Like if it is 00:20:00 , it should only run ls , it should not run the other three .

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You should clarify if you want to do it regularily (periodically), or only occasionally (on demand).

Comment: No regularly at these specific times

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyowrd `at`

For example: `echo "ls -ltr" | at 12:20`

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18945782/6745924). :)