# How to verify scheduled run in linux

Tags: linux, bash, solaris

I am following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945669/how-to-run-a-script-at-a-certain-time-on-linux). I want to run a python script, in the background, after logging out of ssh, witht the output stored into a specific file. Namely, I wish to use the following bash command:

`nohup python3 main.py --dataset CorrSR/testTraining/small --train --input_height=256 --output_height=256  --epoch=2 | at 1:25 PM Mon > logs/background_run_small.txt &`

I am not sure regarding the order of the command. is `|` before `>`? The command runs with no errors, though a process is immediately opened with

> 4285 pts/5    Sl     0:02 /usr/bin/python3 -u /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/start_ipython_kernel.p

and also the output file is immediately created. Is that normal? how do I know the program waits for the designated time to run?

Comment: (general suggestion) Consider starting a `screen` session instead of `nohup`. To fix your command you need to pipe the command to `at`, not the output of your command (`echo "xx --y" | at`). `at` does not need `nohup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line executes `main.py` immediately.

What you probably want is:

```
echo 'nohup python3 main.py --dataset CorrSR/testTraining/small --train --input_height=256 --output_height=256  --epoch=2 > logs/background_run_small.txt' | at "1:25 PM Mon"
```