# How to push the code from cloud9 to Github?

Tags: git, github, cloud9

​I tried lots of times but all failed. My steps shows below

1. add SSH key from cloud9 at my github and connect cloud 9 with my github
2. new a repo called `git@github.com:XXX/XXX.git`​
3. enter the file in cloud 9
4. `git remote add origin git@github.com:XXX/XXX.git`​​
5. `git push -u origin master​`

> ```
> Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>     To git@github.com:XXX/XXX.git​
>      ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
>     error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:XXX/XXX.git​​'
>     hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>     hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>     hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>     hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>     hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
> ```

```
Can some one help me? Thanks a lot!
```

Comment: Try doing `git pull origin master` before you push.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357108/git-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have)

Comment: Thanks! It worked

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of a new repo created on GitHub side *non-empty* (meaning with a `README.md` or `LICENSE` or...)

If you try and create a GitHub repo actually empty, you won't see that error message and won't need to do a `git pull` before your `git push`.