# How can i upload my code on bitbucket without --force

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am newbie on git so my client need to upload code on bitbucket regularly. I have created a repo. and uploaded my first project by these steps in my porject directory

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "my commit"
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
git push origin master
```

And its uploaded successfully. But now when i work on my project i need to upload it. So i just run command again `git push origin master` its showing me error

```
git push to url  ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
```

I know if use `--force`  it will work fine but my i cant use force because there is a team working on project so many people are uploading code regularly so force is causing many problem. I need some good or best practive solution or some type of guide you guys use to this regulary Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357108/git-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do

Answer (score 0):

The reason of your conflict - is a difference between local and remote branch.
Compare git log of them and check last commits. I guess remote brach contains some extra commits, so you should pull them to local branch before pushing your local changes.
Comment message '[rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)' tells you about this situation.