# Can't push merge to server after merging branch with master branch on git

Tags: git, gitlab

Working on a git repository and I merged my new branch with the master branch locally. Now I want to push this merge to the git server but I am getting an error:
Update was rejected because the update contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another reppository pushing to the same ref.

Comment: Before merging master locally, you should have pulled master to get the latest change if any. Someone else may have pushed to master. Could you try taking a git pull, resolve conflicts if any and then try pushing ?

Comment: you need to pull the latest changes from master (origin/remote) to you master local.  Resolve any potential conflicts and push from local to remote master

Comment: Error says that origin repository contains some changes, so you have to pull first and then resolve conflict if any then push

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357108/git-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really common error faced by many people out here so it is not a big issue. You just need to do a `git pull`, which will merge changes made on the remote(*i.e* the GitHub/BitBucket/GitLab repository) while you were working on your code.

After that you can `git push` to push your changes upstream :)

Best.