# This appears when I enter the command "git push origin master". What do I need to do to make the command work?

Tags: git, github, terminal, command, git-push

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Gavinh444/website13.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357108/git-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is a great place to ask questions, however the site requires that you do a minimum of reasearch before asking. For example : the message is pretty detailed, and gives you a guide to the next step, as well as a link to some documentation. These words are also a great fit for a Google search, which would give you a lot of links on how this part of git works. Read the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). See you soon !

Answer (score 0):

That error message says what is wrong, the remote repository has work that you don't have. You need to `git pull` and get that work before you can push.

Comment: Thank you! That worked