# Git: Pushing to a branch that has changes that aren't local

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push to a repo that some merged in changes not in my local.

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.corp.myrepo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
```

I remember using in the past a way to `pull` using `rebase` to resolve this easily where it would pull and also merge your commits.
What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: This topic should be covered in any Git tutorial, and has been asked many times here. Please run through a Git tutorial, and Google the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357108/updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have-loca)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone push new commits to the remote repository after you cloned it

---

to solve the issue you need to pull the commits made by others by using `git pull` , and then solve any conflicts if they appear, and only then you can push your changes to the remote repository

another way is to force the push by `git push -f` , but this is not recommended as it will throw conflict for others