# How can I remove commits from github on my repo?

Tags: github

Whenever I try to update  [my repo](https://github.com/RyckRichards/tatoeba),  I always get this:

http://prntscr.com/ec2osx

Those are my commits:

> git fetch upstream
>
> git checkout dev
>
> git merge upstream/dev

That's what I get on my repo:

"This branch is 3 commits ahead, 11 commits behind Tatoeba:dev."

It's 3 commits ahead according my repo and 11 commits behind since I'm not able to update it.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt in your screenshot is from the editor Git is using as your default editor.  It wants you to enter a message and save to complete the merge.  If your editor is `vi` or `vim` try this:

- hit the "i" button
- write your commit merge message (do not start the line with '#').
- press the "esc" key
- enter the characters ":wq" (without the quotes)
- hit the enter key

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085807/please-enter-a-commit-message-to-explain-why-this-merge-is-necessary-especially) outlines what to do for other editors.

Answer (score 0):

> "This branch is 3 commits ahead, 11 commits behind Tatoeba:dev."

Here you need to merge `Tatoeba:dev` into your local `dev` branch.

```
$ git fetch Tatoeba
$ git checkout dev

$ git pull Tatoeba dev          # pull = fetch + merge
Or, git merge Tatoeba dev 

$ git push origin HEAD
```

Comment: actually, master = dev 
My organization - tatoeba - use dev instead of master

Comment: So, `dev` is Default Branch for your repo?

Comment: Ok. Is `Tatoeba` your another remote? If yes, then you need to merge `Tatoeba` repo's `dev` branch into your local `dev` branch.