# How do you abort git merge at the prompt "Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary."

Tags: git

Right before pulling I ran `git reset HEAD --hard`. Then I `git pull`ed and got the message

> Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary, especially if it merges an updated upstream...

Is it possible to issue a `merge --abort` from the text editor or after entering a merge message following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085807/please-enter-a-commit-message-to-explain-why-this-merge-is-necessary-especially) or do I have to undo the merge after the merge?

My idea: close the terminal, reopen MINGW and then try merge --abort. Will this leave my local repo corrupted?

Comment: If you leave the message empty, it doesn't commit, that's according to the comments inside the message

Comment: Empty commit message would abort the merge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally when git asks you to edit a text file as part of some action, you can abort the action by saving an empty text file. This works for commit messages as well as for, e.g., `git rebase -i`.