# I accidentally set my git editor to Atom, how can I revert it to Git Bash?

Tags: windows, git, github, atom-editor, git-bash

So I encountered an error that said "Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary, especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch" and I found a solution to it in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085807/please-enter-a-commit-message-to-explain-why-this-merge-is-necessary-especially).

However one of the answers said, your text editor is the issue so change it to atom, and without knowing how to use an editor in Atom I changed the git editor to Atom via this code:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

I was using Git Bash, and I wanted to return to that as my core editor, but I can't seem to find a way on how I can do that.

P.S. I am a few days into Git, so pardon any elementary mistakes I make.

Comment: Bash isn’t a text editor. Do you mean reset it to vim? Or would you like something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+set+editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
git config --global --unset-all core.editor
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the editor-setting by git to *Git Bash* command-line, then you can change to the *nano*-editor like following:

`git config --global core.editor "nano"`

So if you enter `git commit -a` after adding files, it would open a file on your terminal where you wrote (e.g. *Git Bash*) the git-command and you can write there your commit-message.

**EDIT:**

With the answer from [Afeef Janjua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981310/i-accidentally-set-my-git-editor-to-atom-how-can-i-revert-it-to-git-bash/61982564#61982564) you reset back the settings for `core.editor` and you will have the same settings as before entering `... core.editor "atom --wait"`.