# Unable to exit "Enter a commit message to explain why this is necessary" in Git Bash on Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, git-bash, git-fork

I am trying to [sync my fork of a repository with the original upstream branch](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork) using the steps given [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork).
After I run the command in step 5. I get a message on the screen saying, Please write a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary...
I write my message and press enter but nothing happens. I tried pressing `esc` `shift + enter` but nothing happens.
I also tried the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085954/13550402) but still, nothing happened.
Please explain how do I complete this step by successfully writing a commit message?

Answer (score 1):

In the ad-hoc editor window you can see hints at the bottom of the screen.

(`^X Exit` is to be understood as `CTRL+X`)

It'll then return the message to be used in your commit.

Comment: It is not working. Nothing happend when I try `CTRL + X`

Comment: Strange. Can you precisely describe the shell program you're using? I (maybe mistakingly?) read from your question that you refered to MING64, the bash client included in Git for Windows. Is it the case?

Comment: I am using this bash [terminal](https://gitforwindows.org/)