# VIM comment hashtag error?

Tags: python, vim, comments, hashtag

I thought that text editors like vim took the # to indicate a comment and pass over those lines.

Here's the content of my ~/.vimrc file:

```
# Testing comments
set nocompatible

# Testing comments
set number
```

But when I run vim, I get this:

Error detected while processing /home/user/.vimrc:

```
line 1:
E488: Trailing characters: # Testing comments
line 4:
E488: Trailing characters: # Testing comments
```

When I remove the comment lines it works fine, but I should like to be able to add comments to my text files without it fouling things up. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Also, I read that I shouldn't use """, as this isn't really commenting.  That and it is also for blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vim` doesn't use `#` for comments; it uses quotation marks. Your `.vimrc` should read

```
" Testing comments
set nocompatible

" Testing comments
set number
```

By your comment regarding `"""`, it seems you are confusing Python comments with Vim comments.

Comment: "*confusing Python comments with Vim comments*" ... not to mention confusing Python strings with Python comments.

Comment: I got really confused when someone used hash comments in their vimrc from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1218390/266535). Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

in .vimrc to write comments you have to use "
your files would look like

```
" Testing comments
set nocompatible

" Testing comments
set number
```