# Opening vim throws an error "Trailing characters"

Tags: vim

My config file is tiny. Here's my full `.vimrc`:

```
# Enable mouse
set mouse=a

" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax on

# Add numbers on the left side
set number
```

Opening vim throws an error "Trailing characters."

Every time I tried to open Vim, these errors showed up. I don't understand the error. So what did I do wrong here?

The error is following:

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy2qt.png]

Text:

```
dana@sunyata ~ % vim .vimrc
Error detected while processing /Users/dana/.vimrc:
line    1:
E488: Trailing characters: Enable mouse: # Enable mouse
line    7:
E488: Trailing characters: Add numbers on the left side: # Add numbers on the left side
line   10:
E488: Trailing characters: Ability to copy from Vim to other software: # Ability to copy from Vim to other software
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

What does "Trailing characters" mean and how do I fix these errors?

Comment: What do you think is the character used for comments in `.vimrc`?

Comment: This is the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409858/vim-comment-hashtag-error. However, it doesn't explain what "trailing characters" means.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Fixed, thanks. Changing comment char from # to " fixed all of the errors. It's my bash habit, oops! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

1. Every line in your `virmc` is an Ex command.
2. `:#` is an Ex command that prints lines so it can't be used for comments. Vim complains about "trailing characters" because you give it erroneous commands like:

   ```
   :# Enable mouse
   ```

   that contain too much junk and thus can't be parsed correctly.
3. Vim uses `"` for comments.

---

1. If you didn't already, do `$ vimtutor` as many times as needed to get the basics right.
2. As instructed at the end of vimtutor, level up to the user manual `:help user-manual`. It's a hands-on tutorial that will guide you progressively through *every* feature, from basic to advanced. This is not a novel, go at your own pace and, most importantly, experiment along the way.
3. Keep an eye on anti-patterns and inefficient actions, find improvements, practice. Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: Recently ran into to this same issue. I was attempting to use `##` as the character used to denote comments. I was following along with this alleged "sane and simple" .vimrc configuration via: https://vimconfig.com/ 

Why would they suggest using # character to denote comment? Was the # symbol used as a comment character in a previous common version?

Comment: Because that that site is a scam created by incompetents and used by fools. Vim never used `#` as comment leader. The funny thing is that the new version of vimscript actually does, but vim9script is an explicit opt-in so it is irrelevant in the context of that `vimrc`.

Answer (score 4):

I had to change the comment character from `#` to `"` in .vimrc config file.

##### Here's a comparison:

The old version with trailing character errors:

```
# Enable mouse
set mouse=a

" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax on

# Add numbers on the left side
set number
```

Fixed version with no errors:

```
" Enable mouse
set mouse=a

" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax on

" Add numbers on the left side
set number
```