# Cut or yank an entire tag in VIM

Tags: html, vim, frontend

Given a common html bit like

```
<div>
  <p>
    Mary had a <b>little</b> lamb.
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to cut the **entire** (not the inner only) `div` for pasting elsewhere. I know there are alternative ways to do this like cutting a range of lines etc., but as a newish user of VIM I sorely need to move around tags in my frontend workflow and I just haven't seen a great way to do this yet.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum I'm guessing it's because he has other tags/text on the same line before the div.

Comment: Found a useful answer about yanking and pasting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118

Comment: @JonathanLandrum sometimes the tag is really large and I cannot see what line number it actually ends on. Secondarily I don't enjoy counting likes beyond like 7 or 8. Maybe I'll develop a better estimation sense as time goes on, but right now I really need to be moving around tags like so many building blocks without mentally switching into counting. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With your cusor on the outer div tag: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

**d** elete **a** round **t** ag

Then paste it with <kbd>p</kbd> where you need it.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I see there are many ways to do it including going into visual mode (which I try to avoid when possible) but this is very direct for my use case.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `at` text-object to act on a whole tag and the `it` text-object to act on the content of a tag.

To act on the current text-object, your command should look like this:

```
operator + text-object
```

You can add a `count` before the text-object to act on `count` levels of surrounding text-objects:

```
operator + count + text-object
```

So, with the cursor on line 1 and 5, you can use the following command to yank the whole `<div>`:

```
yat
```

With the cursor on line 2, 3 or 4, the command becomes:

```
y2at
```

With the cursor inside the `<b>`, the command becomes:

```
y3at
```

That said, I suggest you use visual mode instead of counting: it's more intuitive, safer and potentially faster. Just repeat the text-object to expand your selection:

```
vatat
```

then:

```
y
```

See `:help motion.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

`vatyp` should do that.

`vat` to visually select around tag the cursor is in

`y`   to yank it

`p`   to paste.  Go to the position where you want to paste and use `p` to paste.

Answer (score 1):

xml plugin http://github.com/othree/xml.vim is very handy to edit xml.

with this plugin, when your cursor on `<div>`, press `<leader>D`, will remove the `<div> till </div>` inclusive.

and if you press `<leader>d`, will only remove the `<div> and </div>` tag, change your text into:

```
  <p>
    Mary had a <b>little</b> lamb.
  </p>
```

there are more functionalities,  you may want to check. without the xml plugin, you can press `dat`