# repurpose default key in vim

Tags: vim, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-hook

I heard that there is no internal function to call when typing a key combo in vim, unlike emacs. So I want to repurpose Ctrl-A to ^ (like, nnoremap < C-A> ^); however, the original function of Ctrl-A is also attractive, so I want to map it to some other keys, say Ctrl-S. How can I do this the vim way?

This question might have been asked but I searched around and did not find anything close. Thanks in advance.

PS: the stupid vim-emacs war is spamming everywhere and nowhere can i find a real solution that makes a desired feature to work in another environment.

Comment: Please clarify your post.  Do you mean you want to bind keys in Emacs or in Vim?  What functions/features are you trying to bind?

Comment: no matter which editor you use, try to get used to its keys. map `ctrl-a -> ^` in vim is not good idea, you can map `c-a a to do number+1` however, when you are in screen, tmux (with c-a as prefix), you have to press `ctrl -a a a` to do number+1. And you have to map `ctrl-k, ctrl-f, ctrl-e,ctrl-w ....` then just use emacs, hope you don't map `hjkl` in emacs.

Comment: oh, speaking of key confusion, most times trying to copy something on mac ends up closing that window :-|

Answer (score 2):

The following should do:

```
nnoremap <C-A> ^
nnoremap <C-A>A <C-A>
```

This works because the `noremap` tells vim to do not apply any other mapping, thus the rhs of the second mapping above is the default `<Ctrl-A>`.

You will notice that the first mapping will take a delay to execute, because vim waits a while to allow you to type the second mapping. [Vim-FAQ 20.16](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.16) may help if this bothers you.

But I'd advice against changing the default mapping because, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24424441/717124), vim has many default mappings that may seems silly when you start using it. When you understand it better you  will have a hard time finding another key to map it or to get used to the old/default mappings.

Comment: it did not work for me ... I had vim 7.3. Also, speaking of the ideal key cliche, ^ is really unapproachable for its frequency; or i guess i should really get used to 0w combo?

Comment: It should work on vim 7.3. Without further details it is kind of hard to provide any help.

Comment: even if i just have nnoremap <C-S> <C-A> or nmap <C-S> <C-A>, nothing happens when i press C-S. This is the only line in .vimrc and there is no .vim folder. i am using mac if that might be a problem.

Comment: Try to narrow your problem: is it caused due to the 'from' or the 'to'? E.g.: try mapping <C-S> to something else, as `nnoremap <C-S> iabc` to enter insert mode and insert 'abc'; or try mapping some other key to <C-A>. Also check the Vim-FAQ, in special entries 20.4 and 20.5

Comment: i think this is the issue: firstly <C-A>a should be mapped rather than <C-A>A and secondly <C-S> does not mean Ctrl-S. But otherwise, your solution works. and the comment was pretty good for debugging. Thanks!