# Is there a way to alias vim navigation keys?

Tags: vim

I would like to swap the editor mode functions of '$' with '^' and 'w' with 'b'

I tried writing aliases in my bash profile like usual but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I swear, this is a bad idea.
You'll run into trouble, as soon as you hit the next workstation.
Like really, don't mess with vims default bindings.

Also this question has been asked before :/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416826/changing-default-key-bindings-in-vim

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing default key bindings in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416826/changing-default-key-bindings-in-vim)

Comment: Thank you, I'll tread forward lightly

Comment: Are these just example bindings you're using to see how one would change bindings or is this like a prank binding you want to do on a friend?

Either way, you're going to need a .vimrc (google this) and you'll need to look up how to "remap" (that's the term in vim) the keys.