# IPython forward slash documentation

Tags: python, ipython

I accidentally discovered this feature in IPython:

```
In [126]: def blah(): return 5

In [127]: /blah
Out[127]: 5

In [128]: /range 5 2 4
Out[128]: range(5, 2, 4)

In [133]: /int '100' base=16
Out[133]: 256
```

A line starting with a forward slash will have commas and function call parens automatically inserted.

Where do I find out more? I can't seem to find the docs for it.

Comment: No, but I knew about `_` and `Out[133]`. Thanks.

Comment: Why is `5` the output of `/ 5`?

Comment: @fepegar It looks like putting a space after the slash will make it do nothing to the argument. `/ 1+2` returns `3`. `/ 1 2 3` returns `(1,2,3)`. I guess if `/f a b c` means `f(a,b,c)`, then `/ a b c` turns into `(a,b,c)` (nothing, instead of function name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type `?` in ipython you will get the builtin documentation:

```
 You can force auto-parentheses by using '/' as the first character
     of a line.  For example::

          In [1]: /globals             # becomes 'globals()'

     Note that the '/' MUST be the first character on the line!  This
     won't work::

          In [2]: print /globals    # syntax error

     In most cases the automatic algorithm should work, so you should
     rarely need to explicitly invoke /. One notable exception is if you
     are trying to call a function with a list of tuples as arguments (the
     parenthesis will confuse IPython)::

          In [1]: zip (1,2,3),(4,5,6)  # won't work

     but this will work::

          In [2]: /zip (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
          ------> zip ((1,2,3),(4,5,6))
          Out[2]= [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

     IPython tells you that it has altered your command line by
     displaying the new command line preceded by -->.  e.g.::

          In [18]: callable list
          -------> callable (list)
```

The relevant [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes) page which includes other features.

There is a nice list taken from [here](http://damontallen.github.io/IPython-quick-ref-sheets/svg/Basic_Help.svg) of most basic features:

[image]

Comment: I knew I saw something about auto-parens before, but I couldn't find that page because it doesn't say "slash" on it. I also just learned of `,`/`;` and the search prompt Ctrl+R from the `?` docs.

Comment: @leewangzhong, unless you know the actual term it is not easy to find as the ipython docs are pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Yeah discoverability is a bit weak. I'd be very glad to see "what are your best Ipython commands and tricks" - but I think that would be off-topic for Stackoverflow? (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118)