# Why does Jupyter notebook call the object after / in a line?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I runned this code cell:

```
x = 1
y = 10
/print x y
```

I got the output:
`1 10`

I searched why this works but couldn't find any answers. I would be glad if someone explains why.

Answer (score 0):

[IPython forward slash documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773844/ipython-forward-slash-documentation)

has the same question answered.

In short:

You can force auto-parentheses by using '/' as the first character of a line.  For example:

```
      In [1]: /globals             # becomes 'globals()'
```