# Vim: How would I recursively run ":sort" for everything between curly braces?

Tags: css, vim

I'm a web developer and I often have to write CSS:

I always sort the styling alphabetically so this:

```
.sorted_product_mens_color_list li, .sorted_product_womens_color_list li {
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

turns into:

```
.sorted_product_mens_color_list li, .sorted_product_womens_color_list li {
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

However, this gets repetitive and I want to just automate it by writing a script that does this in VIM.

How would I either 1) run `:sort` in a loop within a file within all curly braces or
2) Run that in all CSS files in a directory? (either one)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a single file you could do :

```
:g/{/normal! f{viB:sort^M
```

What this does :

- `:g/{/` : for every line containing a `{`
- `normal!` : enter normal mode (the `!` simply skips mappings in the command)
- `f{` : find the (first, but this shouldn't be a problem in css (?)) `{`
- `viB` : enter visual mode between the curly brackets
- `:sort` : well... sort the visual selection
- `^M` : press enter (this is a single character, use `<C-v><CR>` to type it)

---

For multiple files you could do :

```
# From you shell
# In zsh you would use 'vim **/*.css' to open all the css files in nested directories
# Not sure about your shell
$> vim *.css     # open css files in the current directory
```

```
" In vim
:argdo g/{/normal! f{viB:sort^M:update^M
```

The `:update` is the same as `:write`, except that it will not trigger a write if the buffer wasn't modified.

Comment: Wow may I ask how you learned this stuff about VIM? I used it everyday but I don't know anything you just wrote

Comment: @edmund : Well I didn't come up with the `:g/{/normal` "trick" by myself, a colleague show me how to use it to merge all lines between brackets. Aside from that, I didn't know about the `!` in `normal!` before this question (ran into a problem with `:normal`, looked up the help and thought it'd be better with the exclamation point). The `f{viB` I would consider ~basic~ (obviously depends on how long you've been using vim). As for the `^M`, I…don't really know. For resources I don't really have any, aside from `:help` (but you'ld need to know what you are looking for…). Vim reddit maybe ?

Comment: @Edmund: Also forgot to mention [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim) which has some really great answers that helped me understand many concepts in Vim when I first started.

Comment: For this, I prefer to use `ex` commands the whole way:  `:g/{/+,/}/-sort`  which seems simpler to me.  Find the lines with "{", starting a range on the next line ("+"), through the line before ("-") the next "}", sort them.

Comment: @Gumnos: Wow yeah, that's much better. I never thought of using a range in the command passed to `:g`, that's really neat. Plus with your way you can get rid of those ugly `^M` and simply use `sort | update`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Gumnos perhaps you could add an answer to this question and explain it further?

Answer (score 9):

At the request of [@Edmund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1555312/edmund), I'll add an answer to explain `:g/{/+,/}/-sort` further.  The `:g` command's syntax is

```
:{range}g/pattern/{ex command(s)}
```

The initial range to consider is blank, defaulting to searching the entire file.  The pattern is `{` which searches for the opening brace.

```
:g/{/{ex command(s)}
```

The command is the remainder.  In this case, that ex command is `+,/}/-sort`.  This breaks down as an optional range ("`+,/}/-`") followed by a command (`sort`) to execute on that range. That range starts at the current line (found by the "`:g`" command) and goes forward one (`+` which would be synonymous with `+1` since the default is 1) line.  Then the "`,`" separates the start of the range from the end of the range.  To find the second line of the range, we search forward for the next closing brace ("`/}/`") and then go back one line ("`-`", again equivalent to "`-1`").  Now that we've defined the range as "from the line following the opening brace that we found, through the line before the closing brace", we execute the `sort` ex command on that range.