# Copy from VIM does not work since Debian Jessie

Tags: vim, debian, vi

Since Debian jessie some change was made to vim which makes it impossible to copy text out with the mouse then reinsert it again with SHIFT+INSERT.

The selection works but it does not autocopy anything to the keyboard.

Any other solution to fix this than remove vim and use the stock vi?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim?rq=1) may be usefull

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't help you with the mouse, but if you just want to access the system clipboard this may help. If you type `vim --version` in the shell and one of the features is `+xterm_clipboard` then you should be able to access X's clipboard with the `+` register. The [Arch wiki has a bit more information](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm#Copy_and_paste) about this.

You can try compiling vim yourself to enable this feature with:

```
./configure --with-x --enable-gui=auto  --with-features=huge
```

Or try installing the `vim-gnome` package which should have that feature enabled.

To use, preface relevant commands with `"+` which instructs vim to use the `+` register. So to copy the current line to the clipboard: `"+yy`. To paste the contents of the clipboard: `"+p`.

Answer (score 0):

Just install vim-gnome

```
sudo apt install vim-gnome -y
```