# Text Editing in VI

Tags: vim, vi

How do I delete text probably multiple lines in vi(m)?

Tried the backspace button to delete. Works not!

Deleted lines of text.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! :) Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Required reading: [Your problem with Vim is that you don't grok vi.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118/240443)

Comment: Also: [vi.se] exists

Answer (score 2):

By default, in Vi/Vim, `backspace` does not work as we are used to] (cf `:help bs`, in Vim).

If you are in Vim, you can set it to behave the way you want with:

```
:set bs=indent,eol,start
```

If you are in Vi only, I refer you to @user31264's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some most common delete commands:

Delete 123 lines from the current one: d123d or 123dd

Delete one line: dd

Delete 1 character: x

Delete 123 characters: 123x

Delete till the end of the current word (word is a sequence of alphanumeric characters, or one non-alphanumeric non-space character): dw or de

As above, word is a sequence of any characters except whitespace: dW or dE

As above, delete 123 words: 123dw, 123de, 123dW, or 123dE